# assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast // ((C))

Tags: c

Tengo este pequeño problema que hace que cuando compilo el código no me devuelva ningún valor.

Adjunto el código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */


int palabra(char letra, char oracion[100]);


int main() {
    printf("%i",palabra('o',"Trineo"));

    return 0;   
}

int palabra(char letra, char oracion[100]){
    letra='o';
    oracion[100]="Trineo";

    int i;
    int contador=0;

for (i=0; i<100; i++){
    if(oracion[i]==letra){
        contador++;
    }

}
return contador;    
}
```

Me dice que el problema está en la linea 8, no sabría porque, agradezco la ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varias fallas en ese código:

**1.-** Estas dos líneas de código no tienen sentido:

```c
letra='o';
oracion[100]="Trineo";
```

Porque los parámetros de la función `palabra` ya tienen sus respectivos valores guardado en memoria. Por lo tanto, **debes eliminar esas sentencias**.

Ten en cuenta que el parámetro `letra` recibe el caracter `o` que pasas por valor y `oracion` recibe la dirección de memoria del primer caracter de la cadena `Trineo`, por lo tanto, a través del puntero `oracion` puedes acceder a dicha cadena (que en realidad es un simple bloque de memoria).

También recalco que este prototipo de función:

```c
int palabra(char letra, char oracion[100]);
```

Es equivalente a:

```c
int palabra(char letra, char* oracion);
```

Por lo tanto, no necesitas especificar el tamaño del *array* en el operador de indexación (`[]`).

A pesar que esta línea de código puede compilar:

```c
oracion[100]="Trineo";
```

Puede ocasionar problemas graves en tiempo de ejecución. Ya que cuando se ejecute la instrucción, realmente no estaríamos asignando la cadena literal, sino, la dirección de memoria del primer elemento de la cadena. Por lo tanto, el código de arriba es como si hicieras esto:

```c
//Aquí asumo que la dirección 0x30 es la del primer elemento de la cadena.
oracion[100]= 0x30;
```

Entonces, esto ocasiona un posible [fallo de segmentación](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Violaci%C3%B3n_de_acceso), ya que estaríamos asignando la dirección `0x30` en un espacio que al programa no le pertenece y esto se debe porque el puntero `oracion` apunta a un bloque de memoria de `6` elementos y como el indice es un `100`, se desborda el búfer (se paso del límite).

Otra consecuencia que también podría ocurrir, sería sobrescribir la memoria del propio programa y esto si es difícil depurar..

**2.-** La condición de salida del bucle for no es la adecuada:

```c
for (i=0; i<100; i++)
```

El parámetro `oración` solo puede acceder a `6` caracteres. Si llegara a sobrepasarse de ese límite, ocurrirá un desbordamiento de búfer y esto ocasiona un posible fallo de segmentación, porque se estaría accediendo a una memoria que no le pertenece al programa.

Así que lo correcto sería usar la función [strlen](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/) para obtener la longitud de la cadena y así poder iterar de forma segura.

Código C:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> //strlen

//Podemos omitir los nombres de los parámetros.
int palabra(char, char*);

int main() 
{
    printf("%i", palabra('o', "Trineo"));
    return 0;   
}

int palabra(char letra, char* oracion)
{
    int i;
    int contador=0;
    int len = strlen(oracion);
    //No hace falta las llaves de apertura y de cierre.
    for (i=0; i<len; i++)
        if(oracion[i]==letra)
            contador++;
    return contador;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Gran respuesta de @MrDave1999, pero hay alguna cosas que no me gustan en el código de la pregunta, aparte de los errores, por ejemplo, escribir las variables directamente en la función, en lugar de pasarles los nombres de las variables. Si no te importa y nadie se siente especialmente ofendido, me gustaría reescribir tu codigo de forma alternativa, además veras cómo es posible escribir el código C de distintas maneras, con un estilo y un formato diferente, creo yo más acorde con C (aunque es cuestion de gustos supongo).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

// prototipo de la funcion
int palabra(char letra, char oracion[]);


int main(void)
{
    char letra ='o';
    char oracion[7] = {'T','r','i','n','e','o','\0'};

    printf("%i\n", palabra(letra, oracion));

    return 0;
}

int palabra(char letra, char oracion[])
{
    int i, contador = 0;
    int n = strlen(oracion);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (oracion[i] == letra)
        {
            contador++;
        }

    }

    return contador;
}
```

Fijate como pasamos un array a la función, solamente con su nombre, e inicializamos las variable en main, de esta forma hacemos más versatil el programa.

Answer (score 0):

estás igualando oracion[100]="Trineo"; cada elemento de oracion es un char y completo es un array de chars que es mas o menos lo mismo que "Trineo". Es importante ver la diferencia . **oracion="Trineo"**

Comment: Aún así, `oracion="Trineo"` saltará error ya que `oracion` es un array (y por definición, su puntero es constante). Lo que busca es `strcpy(oracion, "Trineo");`

Comment: @RogerMirandaPerez `oracion` en este caso es un puntero, por lo tanto, es totalmente válido hacer esta asignación: `oracion = "Trineo"`, ya que simplemente se le está asignando una dirección al puntero.